# asp.net web application timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, state

I have an .net web application that requires windows authentication and seems like it logs out users 20 minutes when they are inactive regardless if I set sessionState timeout="600" in the web.config. Any additional settings that I missed? please help. I am on IIS 7.5

thanks

Comment: It is timing out because it is inactive for 20 minutes.

Comment: Solved! The issue was with Application Pool Idle Timeout. By default that is set to 20 minutes. I changed that to a higher value and problem solve.